# Bike lock bar jiggles in locked position -- indicative of weakness?

Tags: commuter, lock

I've been using the same bike lock for a number of years now (one like, but not necessarily exactly the same as, this [one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002KVOVKC)). I noticed today that when in the locked position there is quite a bit of jiggle to the bottom bar. This may have always been the case to some extent, but either it's gotten worse or it's just the first time that I've actually ever thought about the implications of it. Is this a security weakness? Does it suggest weakness of the lock to any sort of attack more so than if there isn't a jiggle?

Correction: The lock I actually have is [this one.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000FL4Y6K)

Comment: Jiggle, within reason, is of no significance.

Comment: Check the locking mechanism, and compare the amount of jiggling with the amount of cross-over when it's locked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, its a pretty low quality lock to begin with, so I'd go for a better lock to begin with (e.g. Kryptonite Evo Mini 5).

See [this thread](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/5884/silencing-a-rattling-u-lock). I've found that this jiggling happens over the years anyway to a lock (and a lot of locks do it out of the box), but I don't believe it affects the security significantly on a decent lock. Some locks have little rubber O-rings to prevent the rattling when you're moving it (you can buy some at your hardware store and put them on yourself).